# What does it mean by "Path Matrix" and "Transitive Closure" of a graph (Directed and Undirected)?

Tags: graph

I the discussion of various graph algorithms, I see the terms "Path Matrix" and "Transitive Closure" which are not well-defined anywhere.

What does it mean by "Path Matrix" and "Transitive Closure" in case of both Directed and Undirected graphs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think unkulunkulu's answer is pretty complete, but given JMSA seems [unsatisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231245/what-is-the-difference-between-path-matrix-and-transitive-closure), I'll make another attempt.

Let's start not with the path matrix, but with the **[adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)**.  The adjacency matrix is the standard representation of a graph.  If **adj** is the adjacency matrix for some graph **G**, then **adj[i][j]** == **1** if vertex **i** is adjacent to vertex **j** (i.e. there is an edge from **i** to **j**), and **0** otherwise.  In other words, **adj[i][j] == 1** if and only if we can get from vertex **i** to vertex **j** in *one* "step".

Now, let's define another matrix which I'll call **adj2**: **adj2[i][j] == 1** if and only if we can get from vertex **i** to vertex **j** in *two* steps or less.  You might call it a "two-step adjacency" matrix.  The important thing is that **adj2** can be defined in terms of **adj**:

```
def adj2(i,j):
    if adj(i,j) == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        for k in range(0,n): # where n is the number of vertices in G
            if adj(i,k) == 1 and adj(k,j) == 1:
                return 1
    return 0
```

That is, **adj2[i][j]** is **1** if **i** is adjacent to **j** (i.e. **adj[i][j]** == **1**) or if there exists some other vertex **k** such that you can step from **i** to **k** and then from **k** to **j** (i.e. **adj[i][j] == 1 and adj[k][j] == 1**).

As you can imagine, you can use the same logic to define a "three-step" adjacency matrix **adj3**, **adj4**, **adj5**, and so on.  If you go on long enough (e.g. to **adjn**, where **n** is the number of vertices in the graph), you get a matrix that tells you whether there's a path of *any length* from vertex **i** to vertex **j**.  This, of course, would also be the graph's path matrix: **adjn[i][j] == path[i][j] for all i, j**.  (Note: Don't confuse path matrix with [distance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix).)

A mathematician would say that **path[i][j]** is the transitive closure of **adj[i][j]** on the graph **G**.

Transitive closures exist independently from graph theory; **adj** is not the only thing with a transitive closure.  Roughly speaking, all [functions (in the programming sense) that take two arguments and return a Boolean value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) have a transitive closure.

The equality (==) and inequality (<, >, <=, >=) operators are familiar examples of such functions.  These differ from **adj**, however, in that they are themselves *[transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)*.  "**f(i,j)** is transitive" means that if **f(i,j) == true**, and **f(j,k) == true**, then **f(i, k) == true**.  You know that this property is true of, say, the "less than" relation: from **a < b** and **b < c**, you can infer that **a < c**.  The transitive closure of a transitive function **f** is just **f**.

**adj** is not *generally* transitive.  Consider the graph:

```
v1---v2---v3
```

In this graph, **adj** might represent the function **busBetween(city1, city2)**.  Here, there's a bus you can take from v1 to v2 (**adj[1][2] == 1**) and a bus from v2 to v3 (**adj[2][3] == 1**), but there's no bus from v1 directly to v3 (**adj[1][2] == 0**).  There is a bus-path from v1 to v3, but v1 and v3 are not bus-adjacent.  For this graph, **adj** is not transitive, so **path**, which is the transitive closure of **adj**, is different from **adj**.

If we add an edge between v1 and v3,

```
v1---v2---v3
 \        /
   \----/
```

then **adj** becomes transitive: In every possible case, **adj[i][j] == 1** and **adj[j][k] == 1** implies **adj[i][k] == 1**.  For this graph, **path** and **adj** are the same.  That the graph is undirected corresponds to the "[symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation)" property.  If we added loops to each vertex so that v1, v2, and v3 were each adjacent to themselves, the resulting graph would be transitive, symmetric, and "[reflexive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation)", and could be said to represent equality (==) over the set {1,2,3}.

This begins to illustrate how graphs can represent different functions, and how properties of the function are reflected in properties of the graph.  In general, if you let **adj** represent some function **f**, then **path** is the transitive closure of **f**.

For a formal definition of transitive closures, I refer you to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).  It isn't a hard concept once you understand all the math jargon.

Answer (score 9):

*Path Matrix* in graph theory is a matrix sized `n*n`, where `n` is the number of vertices of the graph. The element on the `i`th row and `j`th column is `1` if there's a path from `i`th vertex to `j`th in the graph, and `0` if there is not.

The [Floyd Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm) is often used to compute the path matrix.

The definition doesn't differentiate between directed and undirected graphs, but it's clear that for undirected graphs the matrix is always symmetrical.

*Transitive Closure* is a similar concept, but it's from somewhat different field. Imagine you have a set of objects and for some of them you know that one is definitely better than the other, so you can write `a > b` (">" being the shorthand for "better"). Definitely you should assume that if `a > b` **and** `b > c` then `a > c`. This is called the *transitivity rule*. Then for any two objects you want to know, whether one of them is better than the other, or it's unknown. This is the *closure*: first you have a relation that's possibly not transitive, but after assuming transitivity you can complete it up to a transitive one.

To solve this problem you construct a directed graph, where a vertex corresponds to every of the mentioned objects (`a`, `b`, `c`, etc.) where a directed edge `u -> v` exists if and only if `u > v`. Then you can construct the path matrix defined in the first paragraph and it will give you the answer: obviously, the existence of a path between two vertices is equivalent to existence of a chain of relations as `u > a > b > ... > z > v` so, by the transitivity rule, `u > v`.

As a sidenote for transitive closure, as you asked about both directed and undirected graphs, the example given uses a non-symmetric relation (>), and thereafter the graph was directed, but it's not always the case. Any equivalence relation, for example, always satisfies transitivity but also has to satisfy symmetry, so corresponding graph is undirected. You can find a transitive closure of symmetrical relation (or graph).

Comment: @JMSA, I can't provide a very good link in english, 'cause I learned that from programming trainings and literature was in russian. But I gave a link to wikipedia about floyd's algorithm, I guess there's pretty decent content.

Comment: @JMSA, ok, sorry, I cannot provide a link in russian neither, that were some "metodichka"s not available online :D Wikipedia is fine, I guess. It contains further links at bottom of the page.